# Connect Android to Pervasive database remotely

Tags: android, pervasive

I hope this doesn't come off as rhetorical, but I've been googling in circles and can't find quite what I'm looking for.

I'm very new to Android development and this is probably a lofty goal, but I'm looking to create an app that can connect to the Pervasive database on my file server remotely (not while on the same local network, but from anywhere).

So far, all I can find are answers saying to use MySQL, but the database is not hosted on a web server. I'm not looking for some one to write code for me, I just need resources.

Is this even possible / advisable?

Are there any posts / articles I should read?

Are there any libraries that I'll need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  Is it advisable, that depends.  To access Pervasive PSQL over the network, port 1583 needs to be open.  This is the SQL port.  You need port 3351 for Btrieve.
From Android, you can use the Pervasive JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks. That's good information.  It looks like this is going to be over my head.  I assume I'd have to configure the router somehow and set up some kind of listener on the file server?  I don't suppose there are any good tutorials?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorials other than PSQL documentation.  Opening the port is a function of the router / firewall.  The PSQL engine already listens on those ports. The 1583 / 3351 ports are how all PSQL clients communicate from the client to the server.  You'll need the PSQL engine running on the server (probably already is running).  I do know that it's possible as I wrote a query tool for Android that connected to PSQL at one point.